# Permissions option in CloudDeploy[] choosing an authentication scheme

Tags: cloud-deploy, webservices

I have successfully CloudDeploy'ed APIs using the  $Permissions Options set to Public and Private and a PermissionsKey. These work very well.

I haven't quite understood this: Wolfram documentation mentions that $Permissions can be set to classes of users/requesters: {user1,user2,…} as an explicit list of users - **must** they be registered Wolfram subscribers/customers (free or paid)? Can I not have a non wolfram subscriber authenticate and use the web service?

Is it possible to implement a web service that uses a generic authentication method, such as, one of:
Basic
Bearer
Digest

AFAIK, the PermissionsKey is a special form of authentication which passes _key as a parameter in the URL string - this is not consistent with one of the generic Auth methods above.

many thanks!

Comment: You must have a valid wolfram cloud account ($CloudUserID) in order to make authenticated requests to access a cloud object. Unauthenticated users can access public objects only.

Comment: thanks @dsingh for your response. Would you like to reply as an 'answer' so I can give you credit for it? If this is wolfram policy I will need to keep this in mind for implementation.

Comment: Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have a valid wolfram cloud account ($CloudUserID) in order to make authenticated requests to access a cloud object. Unauthenticated users can access public objects only.